# Invalid column in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query in a stored procedure, it works fine. now I want to add a column the it show error.

My stored procedure code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.test
      @SDate DATETIME =Null
    , @EDate DATETIME=Null
    ,@period int=Null        
AS BEGIN         
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if @period = 1 
    Begin 
       SELECT 
              t.TotalQuote
            , t.QuoteAmount        
            ,t.avgProbQ
            , t2.TotalOrders
            , t2.OrderAmount       
             ,t3.totalSales
            ,t3.Prob
        FROM (SELECT a = 1) a
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 
                  TotalQuote = COUNT(quoteid)
                , QuoteAmount = SUM(totalamount)
                ,avgProbQ=SUM(CloseProbability)/COUNT(CloseProbability)
            FROM dbo.QuoteBase join dbo.OpportunityBase on dbo.QuoteBase.opportunityid=dbo.OpportunityBase.opportunityid   
            WHERE
              Month(dbo.QuoteBase.CreatedOn)=Month(getdate()) And YEAR(dbo.QuoteBase.CreatedOn)=YEAR(GETDATE())
        ) t
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 
                  TotalOrders = COUNT(salesorderid)
                , OrderAmount = SUM(totalamount) 
            FROM dbo.SalesOrderBase join dbo.OpportunityBase on dbo.SalesOrderBase.Opportunityid=dbo.OpportunityBase.Opportunityid 
         Where Month(dbo.SalesOrderBase.CreatedOn)=Month(getdate()) And YEAR(dbo.SalesOrderBase.CreatedOn)=YEAR(GETDATE())
        ) t2
        CROSS Join(
        SELECT
        TotalSales=COUNT(dbo.OpportunityBase.opportunityid)
        ,Prob=SUM(CloseProbability)/COUNT(CloseProbability)

        FROM dbo.OpportunityBase join dbo.SalesorderBase on dbo.SalesOrderBase.Opportunityid=dbo.OpportunityBase.Opportunityid
            WHERE Month(dbo.OpportunityBase.CreatedOn)=Month(getdate()) And YEAR(dbo.OpportunityBase.CreatedOn)=YEAR(GETDATE())
            And dbo.SalesorderBase.StateCode=4
            )t3
    END
```

It works fine but when I add a new column like `t.test`, then it shows error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'test'.

If anyone has an idea please share with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but guessing, if you are trying to add a column to the ***output*** of stored procedure, that is not in the table that the stored procedure is reading data from, then you have to put a literal expression into the select clause, with a defined column name like below: This example uses a string literal, but it can be any datatype...

```
 SELECT 'A String literal to be added to output' As  NewColumnName,
      t.TotalQuote
    , t.QuoteAmount        
    ,t.avgProbQ
    , t2.TotalOrders
    , t2.OrderAmount       
     ,t3.totalSales
    ,t3.Prob
  etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your table looked like 
it seems you are adding test to your stored procedure but its not added in your database table

This is what I can say by looking the error message. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the column `test` does not exist in this query:

```
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
          TotalQuote = COUNT(quoteid)
        , QuoteAmount = SUM(totalamount)
        ,avgProbQ=SUM(CloseProbability)/COUNT(CloseProbability)
    FROM dbo.QuoteBase join dbo.OpportunityBase on dbo.QuoteBase.opportunityid=dbo.OpportunityBase.opportunityid   

    WHERE
      Month(dbo.QuoteBase.CreatedOn)=Month(getdate()) And YEAR(dbo.QuoteBase.CreatedOn)=YEAR(GETDATE())
) t
```

but, if you were to add to that query a column named `test` then it would succeed. It could be a string literal like `'Some literal value' AS test` if necessary.